# Auto generated row disappears after reloading table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am making a sum row at the bottom of the table with jquery like this:

```
function sum_sales_table() {

var result = [];

// iterate over each row and find all the numbers that are needed to sum up.
$('#table_sales > tbody > tr').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("id") != "bootstrap-overrides"){
        $('td.sumtable', this).each(function(index, val){
            // sum up the numbers and give in to result array.
            if(!result[index]) result[index] = 0;
            result[index] += parseFloat($(val).text());
        });
    }
});

// create and design the sum row
$('#table_sales > tbody:last-child').append('<tr id="bootstrap-overrides" class="greenrow"></tr>');
$('#table_sales > tbody:last-child > tr:last').append('<th class="align-middle"><i class="fa fa-hashtag fa-md"></i></th>');
$('#table_sales > tbody:last-child > tr:last').append('<th>Total</th>');

// print the sum row numbers
$(result).each(function(i){
    if (i == PROFIT_INDEX){
        $('#table_sales > tbody:last-child > tr:last').append('<th id="total_sum_profit">'+ parseFloat(this) +'</th>')
    }
    else if (i == PROMOTED_INDEX){
        $('#table_sales > tbody:last-child > tr:last').append('<th id="total_sum_promoted">'+ parseFloat(this) +'</th>')
    }
    else if (i == EBAYTAX_INDEX){
        $('#table_sales > tbody:last-child > tr:last').append('<th id="total_sum_eBay_tax">'+ parseFloat(this) +'</th>')
    }
    else{
        $('#table_sales > tbody:last-child > tr:last').append('<th>'+ parseFloat(this) +'</th>')
    }
    
});

// fill out blank columns
$('#table_sales > tbody:last-child > tr:last').append('<th></th>')
$('#table_sales > tbody:last-child > tr:last').append('<th></th>')
```

}

and calling this function on document ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    sum_sales_table();
}
```

This works completely fine on page load. But when I refresh only the div, the row disappears.

This is the function that makes the row to disappear:

```
function return_sale(){
tr = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr")

if (tr.attr('id') == "bootstrap-overrides"){
    // sale is coming back to life
    tr.attr("id", "");

    $.ajax({
        url: "/cancel_return_sale",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            sale_id: $(this).data('id'),
        },
        success:function(data){
            // update total profit
            $("#total-profit").html(parseFloat(parseFloat($("#total-profit").text().replace('$', '')) + parseFloat(data.profit)))

            tr.toggleClass('warningrow');
            // reload sales table and sum row
            $("#table_sales").load(location.href + " #table_sales");

            //update balance
            $("#div_user_balance").load(location.href + " #div_user_balance")
            $("#balance_modal_title").load(location.href + " #balance_modal_title")
        }
    })
    .fail(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

probably it's the $("#item").load(location.href + "#item") line that makes this happen though I can't tell why.
I also tried calling the sum_sales_table() on the table load and also immidiatly after the table refresh.

Comment: Let me confirm:  you display a table, then use js to add a row to that table, then use ajax to *completely overwrite the table including your new row*, then you're asking where your row went?

Comment: Add `sum_sales_table();` at the end of your `success:` callback

Comment: @freedomn-m Not exactly. I use js to add a new row to the table on page load. then I modify the table by overwriting one row (the function return_sale()) and the js generated row disappears. I already tried to add sum_sales_table(); to the end of success. didn't work.

Comment: `$("#table_sales").load(location.href + " #table_sales");` overwrites the table, including deleting the js-added sum row.   Unless your server-side includes the sum-row then it won't be included here.

Comment: If you're changing something when `return_sale()` finished, then that's your error - your code runs too soon an isn't waiting for the *asynchronous* ajax to finish.  You've not included any code that calls `return_sale()`, this is only based ony our comment above.

Comment: @freedomn-m I didn't add any code that calls return_sale() because it's only a button click and irelevant. Still I can't understand why even if I call the sum_sales_table() function in the success block it won't work...